# R language checking some codes

Tags: r, anova

Hello i need Your help

i have database called datasetE and this this inside it

```
datasetE <- data.frame('GPA in Math'=round(runif(29,1.25,3.99),1),'GPA in IT'=round(runif(29,1,3.99),1))
```

this this my teacher question

**For the datasetE ,  test the hypothesis at 95% significance level whether the two population means are equal or not assumed that their variances are equal.**

I answered like this but im not sure if i did right can you check it

```
t.test(datasetE,var.equal = TRUE,conf.level = 0.95)
```

---

also I have this database

```
datasetG <- data.frame('Group'=c(rep("Btech", each=15),rep("Advanced",each=15),rep("Diploma",each=15)),'GPA in IT'=round(runif(45,1,3.99),1))
```

and this the question

**For datasetG, test whether the means of the three groups are different from one another at 99% significance level**

i did like this

```
anova(lm(GPA.in.IT~Group,datasetG))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, you have to mention two groups in the formula, if they are in different columns

```
> t.test(datasetE$GPA.in.Math, datasetE$GPA.in.IT, var.equal = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95, paired = FALSE)

    Two Sample t-test

data:  datasetE$GPA.in.Math and datasetE$GPA.in.IT
t = -0.54788, df = 56, p-value = 0.586
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5459182  0.3114354
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 2.558621  2.675862
```

You can clearly see the hypothesis, *"true difference in means is not equal to 0"*. In your code, the hypothesis would have been, "true mean is not equal to 0", which meant that the test had been performed for one variable as one sample t.test.

For the second text, if you need the residual standard error, you have to run the first code and then the second.

```
> summary(aov(GPA.in.IT~Group, datasetG))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Group        2   1.14  0.5722   0.688  0.508
Residuals   42  34.91  0.8313
```

If it is 99% confidence, Pr(>F) should be less than 0.001